# C program crashes after strcpy

Tags: c, unix

I have tried troubleshooting this problem and just ended up with nothing, I hope you can hint me in the right direction. I have a program where I initialized a char array this way :

```
char variable1[8];
```

And then I try to copy a return value of a function i.e

```
...
strcpy(variable1, (char *)function1());
```

Where function1() returns char array value.
Here is the structure of function1 :

```
 char* function1()
{
    ....
    char variable2[8]={'\0'};
    ...
    return (variable2);
}
```

The program crashes when I try to execute the strcpy line.

I have read on strcpy function [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings#The_strcpy_function) that

> Important: You must ensure that the destination buffer (s1) is able to contain all the characters in the source array, including the terminating null byte. Otherwise, strcpy() will overwrite memory past the end of the buffer, causing a buffer overflow, which can cause the program to crash

Therefore I tried to increase variable1 size to 20, but still the program crashes.

Aside from that, I tried different approach i.e use strncpy function call, and it is still giving me the same error.

The strange thing is that I could execute function1() which returns a value without a problem. Only when I tried to copy it over, my program crashes. Any ideas what I should do next?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. And ask the compiler all the warnings it can give you (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra`) then improve your source till no warnings are given.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not because your destination buffer is too small, it's because the variable containing the source string has gone out of scope before you try to use it.

Within `function1`, `variable2` is created on the stack but this is effectively destroyed when you exit the function. Trying to use it afterwards (such as in a `strcpy` operation) is undefined behaviour.

If you want an array that will survive function exit, you probably want to allocate it from the heap:

```
char *function1 (void) {
    return calloc (1, 8);    // allocate and zero out 8 bytes
}
```

and remember to free the pointer afterwards.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say here, but the content of the function1 itself adds null terminator i.e please refer to the edited question above where i have added the contents of function1(). So now, what could be the problem?

Comment: @vampirus87: you've changed the question considerably from the initial version, so I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Right, yeah, I realised tht adding the function1's content has a huge impact that's why. In other words you are saying that the variable is out of scope right. But then here 'strcpy(variable1, (char *)function1());' I'm using the function1() call right, technically it should still work right?

Comment: No, caller calls function1 which makes a copy of the address of the stack variable and gives it back to the caller on exit. Also at exit, the stack frame for function1 disappears, making the pointer invalid. Then caller uses that address in the strcpy. Boom, crash, opera. Lights out, you done and dusted, and various other metaphors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a `char` value isn't a `char*`, and casting it doesn't make it so (it just makes the compiler stop complaining). So the program crashes because it's trying to dereference an invalid pointer.

Try:

```
variable[0] = function1();  // store the returned character
variable[1] = 0;            // make sure there's a terminating null char
```